# Leaflet Touch Events not firing

Tags: javascript, leaflet, touch, dom-events, openstreetmap

```
    // Setup map
var polymap = L.map('map').setView([51.932994, 4.509373], 14);

// Setup tilelayer
var mapquestUrl = 'http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    subDomains = ['otile1', 'otile2', 'otile3', 'otile4'],
    mapquestAttrib = 'Data, imagery and map information provided by <a href="http://open.mapquest.co.uk" target="_blank">MapQuest</a>,' 
    + '<a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a> and contributors.';
var osm = L.tileLayer(mapquestUrl, {
    attribution: mapquestAttrib,
    subdomains: subDomains
});
polymap.addLayer(osm);

polymap.on('mousedown touchstart', function onMouseDown(event) {
    alert("start");
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4q4mfbb/9/)

Leaflet should normally fire the `touchstart` event as it does with the `mousedown` event, but using a mobile phone, I get no event fired.

Can somebody tell me if there's any mistake in the code, that prevents the `touchevent` from firing?

Answer (score 1):

I have added touch events to leaflet in a branch https://github.com/lee101/Leaflet/tree/add-mobile-touch-events

There is still a problem with touchend events not getting fired if a touchstart event happens on a map control.

You can build the source with `npm install && jake` after you clone the repository.

I should hopefully contribute it back after i fix that issue.

Comment: So, this seems to be the answer to [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37896208/leaflet-multipolygonfield-widget-not-receiving-touch-events) about MultipolygonField widget where one is not able to create points on mobile phone?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to get normal touch events working properly with leaflet map because the map itself use touch events to permit zoom & pan function.

To avoid this issue, you may use this 
[library](http://ngryman.sh/jquery.finger/) to catch specific touch event (tap,double tap,press,flick,drag)

```
<script src="http://domain.ltd/path/jquery.finger.js"></script>


$.Finger = {
    pressDuration: 300,
    doubleTapInterval: 300,
    flickDuration: 150,
    motionThreshold: 5
};

polymap.on('tap', function(e) {
    alert("start");
});
```

Best regards